# How do I set a Python class's attribute if I do not know at compile-time what attribute name will be.?

Tags: python

How do I set a Python class's attribute if I do not know at compile-time what attribute name will be (it gets read from a file with some redirection).   I was hoping `self[attrName]=attrvalue` would work but I get the error `Error 'ManifestReader' object does not support item assignment`

Here is a minimum complete verifiable example (MCVE)

```
class ManifestReader(object):

    def Read(self):
        try:
            ### read a file here
            ### don't know attribute name at compile time
            ### so need to use self[attrName]=attrValue syntax
            attrName="foo"
            attrvalue="bar"
            self[attrName]=attrvalue

            ### above line causes the following error
            '''
            "Error 'ManifestReader' object does not support item assignment"
            "Press any key to continue . . ."           
            '''
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error " + str(e))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    rdr=ManifestReader()
    rdr.Read()
```

If there a better parent class I can inherit from?

Comment: You are trying to treat the object as a map, rather than setting an attribute.

Comment: Side-note: You mean you don't have the name *until* runtime. If you don't have the name *at* run-time, you can't do very many useful things at all.

Comment: ah, its a duplicate, but cannot delete.

Answer (score 1):

Use `setattr`:

```
setattr(self, attrName, attrvalue)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hasattr`, `setattr`, `getattr` to do this.

```py
if hasattr(obj, "attribute_name"):
     setattr(obj, "attribute_name", value)
```